# Find the probability density function of $Y=X+Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is

$$f(x_1,x_2) = 6e^{-3x_1-2x_2}, x_1 >0; x_2>0$$

Find the probability density function of $Y=X_1+X_2$

We did this as a class example but never finished it and I just got stuck because I don't really understand this method.

The method is to find the cumulative distribution function and then derive it to get the p.d.f.

$$P(Y \leq y) = F(y)$$

$$=\int_0^y \int_0^{y-x_2} f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$$

Is this correct. Why is that? Are we just saying that first we integrate to $x_1 = y-x_2$ but then for the outer integral, we take that all the way to y.

$$=6 \int_0^y \int_0^{y-x_2}e^{-3x_1-2x_2}dx_1dx_2$$

$$= 6 \int_0^y [-\frac{e^{-3x_1-2x_2}}{3}]_0^{y-x_2} dx_2$$

but now what happens with the y? How do we integrate in terms of $x_2$ with a y floating around?

Comment: $y = x_1+x_2$ first integral is ok $(0,y-x_2)$ but the last integral should be $(0,\infty)$. the pdf that results should be a function of $y$ since you are looking for $P(Y)$ right? If i get time i will write an answer to explain the other questions.

Comment: why would the second integral be to infinity. Surely for this c.d.f integrating to infinity would mean that we are always going to get 1 because that would mean $x_1+x_2= \infty$

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $$P(Y \le y) = P(X_1 + X_2 \le y)$$

How to do that? One idea is to think: Do I have the distribution function of the vector $(X_1 \ \ X_2)$ ? And the answer is yes, because you have the joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Why is this important? Because now you just need to integrate this density over an "area", that is to say the set of points on the plane where $X_1 + X_2 \le y$

This is semi-plane on the $X_1 \ \ / \ \ X_2 $ plane, so draw the line $X_1 + X_2 \le y$, and integrate over the resulting figure. (taking into account the fact that the density is zero outside the first quadrant, you'll end up integrating over a triangle)

So this should explain the setup, assuming you know how to integrate over triangles. Finally, $y$ is just a constant in this setting, so treat $y$ as you would treat a number like $7$.

Comment: Thank you. But why is y a constant in this setting. Is y not equal to $x_1+x_2$

Comment: Oh wait I see. We're trying to find the c.d.f F(y) so it is for a constant y but a general c.d.f that works for any y

Comment: @StephanCasey No. Do not confuse $Y$ the random variable, with $y$ the number where we are calculating the CDF of $Y$. If it confuses you, you can write $l$ in lieu of $y$, and calculate $P(Y \le l)$. $l$ only means the point where you calculate the CDF